# Does the NICs have any kind of log?

Tags: networking, hardware, crash

Recently I had an issue with my server, my nagios couldn't ping it and lost connection with the NRPE daemon, in my host provider interface I could see the server was ACTIVE but either I couldn't ping it from my network so I had to restart it from the interface directly.

I'm realizing it could be a NIC issue. Any advice?

Comment: Any NICs related issue reports to /var/log/messages or dmesg

Answer (score 0):

if you are not able to ping then there few things you could check before restarting the interface:

**resolv.conf**: make sure you are pinging to IP as well as hostname. ping to gateway or any host within the same subnet to make sure there is no issue there. please note that sometime gateway ping is block so ping to an address that you are sure it is not blocked.

```
     #ping mit.edu
     #ping 8.8.8.8
```

if you can ping by IP address but not by hostname, then make sure you have correct DNS name servers setup in /etc/resolv.conf file

```
     #less /etc/resolv.conf
```

**traceroute** : If you cannot ping your server at all, use traceroute to trace network problem. traceroute provides the detailed information about path to a network server. You can always find out if server is down from your own workstation or gateway router

```
    #traceroute mit.edu
```

**route** : if traceroute point out that you cannot reach to your own gateway then checkout routing setting :

```
    #route
```

**ifconfig**
  : You can check if there is any report of error count on RX or TX. if you found any error count you may want to check switch or with your network admin to clarify if there is any issue on their side

```
    # ifconfig -a
      eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:XX:XXX:XX:XX
      inet addr:172.16.33.74  Bcast:172.16.33.79  Mask:255.255.255.240
      inet6 addr:XXXXXXXXXXXXX/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:831836 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:400887 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:646034732 (616.1 MiB)  TX bytes:337464272 (321.8 MiB)
```

**Error Reports** : Check if there is any error were reports on /var/log or dmesg

```
  # dmesg | less


  # tail -f /var/log/messages
```